# Image Overlaps Figcaption in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, css-grid

I am using media queries and breakpoints to make my webpage responsive. I have 3 images with figcaptions. Everything is fine when the three images are in separate columns. However, for the mobile layout, everything is in the same column. In safari, the mobile layout experiences the following problem: the image overlaps the figcaption. This issue does not occur in firefox or chrome. Unfortunately, since I have no idea what is causing this issue, I don't know how to condense the code and still reproduce the bug. I am using css grid to layout my page (some elements are themselves grids as well). Thank you so much.

Screenshots of Part of Page:

Chrome: (working)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEwFU.jpg)

Safari (not working)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzeeW.jpg)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <title>Name</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <header class="header">
                <h1 class="header-logo">D</h1>
                <div class="header-text">
                    <h1 class="header-name">Name</h1>
                    <h2 class="header-title">Title</h2>
                </div>
            </header>
            <img class="large-image" src="images/code.jpg">
            <main class="main">
                <h2 class="featured-work">Featured Work</h2>
                <figure class="project-1">
                    <img src="images/project-1.jpg">
                    <figcaption class="caption">
                        <div>
                            <h2 class="caption-header">Project 1</h2>
                            <a class="caption-link" href=#>Project Link</a>
                        </div>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure> 
                <figure class="project-2">
                    <img src="images/project-2.jpg">
                    <figcaption class="caption">
                        <div>
                            <h2 class="caption-header">Project 2</h2>
                            <a class="caption-link" href=#>Project Link</a>
                        </div>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure> 
                <figure class="project-3">
                    <img src="images/project-3.png">
                    <figcaption class="caption">
                        <div>
                            <h2 class="caption-header">Project 3</h2>
                            <a class="caption-link" href=#>Project Link</a>
                        </div>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure> 
            </main>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #7d97ad;
    font-style: normal;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
img, embed, object, video {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.caption-header {
    margin: 0;
    color: #2d3c49;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
a {
    color:#337ab7;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover, a:focus {
    color:#23527c; 
    text-decoration:underline;
}
a:focus {
    outline:5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
    outline-offset:-2px;
}
.caption {
    text-align: center;
}
.header-logo {
    margin: 0;
    color: #42c5f4;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    grid-area: hdlg;
}
.header-text {
    text-align: center;
    grid-area: hdtxt;
}
.header-name {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 100;}
.header-title {
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.featured-work {
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    grid-area: ftwk;
}
.project-1 {
    margin: 0;
    grid-area: prjone;
}
.project-1 img {
    width: 100%;
}
.project-2 {
    margin: 0;
    grid-area: prjtwo;
}
.project-2 img {
    width: 100%;
}
.project-3 {
    margin: 0;
    grid-area: prjthree;
}
.project-3 img {
    width: 100%;
}
.header {
    grid-area: header;
    display: grid;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #7d97ad;
    grid-template-areas:
    "hdlg"
    "hdtxt";
}
.large-image {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    grid-area: limg;
}
.main {
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-area: main;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "ftwk"
    "prjone"
    "prjtwo"
    "prjthree";
}
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "header"
    "limg"
    "main";
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .header {
        grid-template-columns: 90px 1fr;
        grid-template-areas:
        "hdlg hdtxt";
    }
    .header-logo {
        text-align: left;
    }
    .header-text {
        text-align: right;
    }
    .main {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        grid-template-areas: 
        "ftwk ftwk ftwk"
        "prjone prjtwo prjthree";
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    body {
        width: 800px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of both it working in chrome and not in safari?

Comment: Ok, I added the screenshots.